# Set WordWrap = false for a Label

Tags: .net, winforms

How should I set `WordWrap = false` to a `System.Windows.Forms.Label`?

I have a header on a panel, and it should show `"MyPanel capt..."`. So I use `AutoEllipsis = true`, but it is not sufficient.

I also use "`AutoSize = true`", because I want that the label takes the minimum space possible.

Apropos, [Visual Basic 6.0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic#Timeline) did it.

Comment: What visual effect are you trying for?

Comment: I had a similar problem, did't find a satisfactory solution. You may want to check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13935275/prevent-word-wrap-in-label-with-autosize-false/53016161#53016161).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
this.label.AutoEllipsis = true;
this.label.AutoSize = true;
```

In the **panel**'s event handler for Resize:

```
...
textHeight = this.label.Font.SizeInPoints; // Take in pixels, not points
...
Size newMaxSize = new Size(this.Width,
    textHeight + label.Padding.Top + label.Padding.Bottom);
this.label.MaximumSize = newMaxSize;
...
```

Answer (score 8):

I've got a similar effect working using:

```
label1.AutoSize = false;
label1.AutoEllipsis = true;
```

and sizing the label area to be one line in height only.

Comment: I use also "AutoSize = true", because want that the label take minimum space possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can't prevent labels from wrapping. An alternate (if slightly crude) option is to set the label to auto-size (so the width grows with the text), and then put a Control next to it that sits in front of it in the z-order. That way, when the label width goes past a certain point the content of the label overlap will be hidden by that other control.

Like I said, it is a pretty crude method of achieving the effect.

Also, if you are trying to use AutoEllipsis, i'm assuming you've disabled AutoResize? I believe it takes precedence.

Comment: No, I use both. AutoEllipsis for the maximum size. Autosize for minimum place.

Comment: Ah, ok, well I think AutoSize will just increase the size of the label to the point that AutoEllipsis is no longer needed.

Comment: AutoEllipsis is needed when the label atteints the parent width. see my answer for the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the labels MaximumSize Property.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way to do this - labels aren't single- or multi-line, per se. It just depends on whether the `Text` property of the label has any line breaks in it.

If you want it to be single line, replace the CRLF characters in the `Text` with something else.

Comment: If I have a long phrase without line breaks it passes to the new line. see the explications in update.

Comment: The reverse: *[Label word wrapping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9509147/label-word-wrapping/10069986#10069986)*

Comment: That is not true. I have no return or line feed characters, yet it is still autowrapping to become multi-lined

Comment: @BernoulliLizard This may be true now - I answered this question 10 years ago and if it's different now and auto-wrapping, that may have been a feature that was added to .NET since then.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I think I finally understand the effect you want.

You want a label that will AutoSize up to a maximum amount. After the maximum, you want to show AutoEllipsis. Correct?

If so, then you need to set the MaximumSize, AutoEllipsis, and AutoSize properties. Then the label will be as small as possible. When the text exceeds the maximum size you specified, the text will be truncated and an ellipsis appended. You do not need code to do this.

Comment: Yes; you understood correctly. But the problem is setting MaxSize. parent panel is resiezible, so see my answer for the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a FlowLayoutPanel to hold the labels with left to right flow.  So autosize and overlap breaks my nicely aligned columns.  I think the most direct way is to just implement paint yourself. Helpers exist to do the ellipsis for you.

That last TextFormatFlags has a dozen options which save you tons of annoying drawing code.

```
    private void templateLabel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Label lbl = sender as Label;
        e.Graphics.Clear(lbl.BackColor);

        TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, lbl.Text, lbl.Font,
            lbl.ClientRectangle,
            Color.Black,
            lbl.BackColor, TextFormatFlags.EndEllipsis);
    }
```