# Label word wrapping

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

Is there a way to do a word wrap in a [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) label control?

I know there is an alternate way of using a [TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), make property *BorderStyle* to none, property *ReadOnly* to true and set property *WordWrap* and property *Multiline* to true.

Is there something for a label?

Comment: I don't think there is, but been quite a while since I did WinForms.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Refer to *[Automatically Wrap Text in Label](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/97c18a1d-729e-4a68-8223-0fcc9ab9012b/)*. It describes how to create your own growing label.

Here is the full source taken from the above reference:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class GrowLabel : Label {
  private bool mGrowing;
  public GrowLabel() {
    this.AutoSize = false;
  }
  private void resizeLabel() {
    if (mGrowing) return;
    try {
      mGrowing = true;
      Size sz = new Size(this.Width, Int32.MaxValue);
      sz = TextRenderer.MeasureText(this.Text, this.Font, sz, TextFormatFlags.WordBreak);
      this.Height = sz.Height;
    }
    finally {
      mGrowing = false;
    }
  }
  protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnTextChanged(e);
    resizeLabel();
  }
  protected override void OnFontChanged(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnFontChanged(e);
    resizeLabel();
  }
  protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e) {
    base.OnSizeChanged(e);
    resizeLabel();
  }
}
```

Comment: I am trying to add  a new property to existing label, like AutoSize, something like IsWordWrap=true. Any thoughts? so that i can give 
LabelName.IsWordWrap=true;

Comment: TextRenderer.MeasureText in my case gave wrong size. To make everything perfect you need also override OnPaint and draw text like this: `TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, this.Text, this.Font, new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, Int32.MaxValue), ForeColor, TextFormatFlags.WordBreak);`

Answer (score 241):

Change your maximum size,

```
label1.MaximumSize = new Size(100, 0);
```

And set your autosize to true.

```
label1.AutoSize = true;
```

That's it!

Comment: You may need `using System.Drawing;` too.

Comment: Agree, this is the best and easier to implement answer, just tested it and works perfect

Comment: This seem like too magic to me... Also (and more obscure), you need to have autosize Off before doing this.

Comment: Change this to label1.MaximumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 0); And this works.

Comment: For me, this causes other controls to get clipped by the container despite it also having the AutoSize property.

Comment: This works also in the Designer

Answer (score 52):

Just set Label AutoSize property to False. Then the text will be wrapped and you can re-size the control manually to show the text.

Answer (score 23):

Ironically, turning off `AutoSize` by setting it to `false` allowed me to get the label control dimensions to size it both *vertically* and horizontally which effectively allows word-wrapping to occur.

Answer (score 14):

If you open the dropdown for the `Text` property in Visual Studio, you can use the enter key to split lines. This will obviously only work for static text unless you know the maximum dimensions of dynamic text.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for (how to split lines in the designer).

Comment: heaps better answer!

Answer (score 5):

If you want some dynamic sizing in conjunction with a word-wrapping label you can do the following:

1. Put the label inside a panel
2. Handle the `ClientSizeChanged event` for the panel, making the
   label fill the space:

   ```
   private void Panel2_ClientSizeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       label1.MaximumSize = new Size((sender as Control).ClientSize.Width - label1.Left, 10000);
   }
   ```
3. Set `Auto-Size` for the label to `true`
4. Set `Dock` for the label to `Fill`

Answer (score -5):

You can use a `TextBox` and set `multiline`  to `true` and `canEdit` to `false` .

Comment: multiline and canEdit aren't actual properties on TextBox.