# Prevent word wrap in label with AutoSize=false

Tags: c#, winforms

How to prevent word wrapping in Label control in designer mode, while it's auto size is set to false?

Basically I want to freely move and resize label in designer mode, but its text should be always in one line (cut if needed).

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think to do it is to create a custom control that inherits Label and override the OnPaint method.

```
public class CustomLabel : Label
{
    public CustomLabel()
    {            
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, new SolidBrush(ForeColor), 0, 0);
    }
}
```

The downside is that if you want to take into account TextAlign, Padding and Margin you'll need to calculate it yourself in the paint method.

Answer (score 5):

Do you want to prevent it **only** in designer mode or also at runtime?

As you mentioned 'cut if needed!'

I suggest you to look at:
[Label.AutoEllipse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.autoellipsis.aspx)

Comment: unfortunly AutoEllipse doesn't change labels behavior in designer mode. And yes, I don't care about runtime, only designer mode.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a good solution to this problem yet, so sharing what I did.
Use the 'String.Right' function. You could also control the length of the string based on the label width. An example using VB is below. It's not exactly a clean solution to your problem, but an easy fix.

```
myLabel.Text = Strings.Right(myString, 50)
```

Or

```
myLabel.Text = Strings.Right(myString, CInt(mylabel.Width*0.25))
```